# SD card supported by Android 4.2.2

Tags: sd-card, htc-desire

I bought a HTC 310 Desire running Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean) and would like to format my SD card (SDHC 32GB) so to be able to contain files larger than 4GB.
I tried formatting the card exFAT, NTFS, ext2, ext4 (using the utility of my Windows PC, of a MAC and using MiniTool PartitionWizard) but when i place back the card into the phone, the phone keep saying that the card is damaged and propose to reformat it. If I accept the card will be formatted as FAT32 (i.e. no file larger than 4GB possible).
Do you know what can be done? Possibly without rooting the phone?
Is there somewhere a list of the file system supported by my phone?
Or is there something special to pay attention to in the card formatting?

Answer (score 2):

I have looked into this issue before, and as it stands at the moment, native android does not support exFAT or NTFS.

Support for additional formatting types are included in some ROMs because they have been specifically coded to do so such as AFAIK which I believe supports NTFS.

I think you are stuck with FAT32 unless you wish to root and flash a ROM that supports alternative formats.

Comment: I fear you are right. No support for anything else than FAT32. Nevertheless I recently managed to format a SD card as exFAT and make it recognized on a sony xperia z3 android 4.4.4. In that case formatting with the Windows tool and MiniTool PartitionWizard did not work while formatting with MAC did work. So I hoped that finding the magic formatting parameters I can still make it working. Or maybe is my phone and it's android version the cause of the problem?

Comment: @luca The main problem with exFAT is that it is [patent encumbered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Restrictive_licensing_and_software_patents), so many manufacturers choose not to support it in order to avoid paying licensing fees. Samsung often supports it, and Sony apparently did (for your Xperia Z3, at least), but HTC may not.