# Does Android Jelly Bean supports NTFS SD card formatting?

Tags: sd-card, formatting, ntfs

If I format my micro SD card as NTFS, will my phone see it? I need this because I want to transfer files larger than 4GB on my phone microSD card, but FAT32 allows just files up to 4GB.

Comment: Can you just check?..

Answer (score 3):

Honestly speaking, It depends on the manufacturer. As far as I am aware, the company has to get some license from Microsoft to include NTFS support. Speaking from experience, most (high-end) Samsung and HTC phones do while custom roms typically do not.

The only sure-shot method to confirm is by trying it out with an extra sd card...

Answer (score 2):

I've already found an similar issue: [SD card supported by Android 4.2.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98494/sd-card-supported-by-android-4-2-2)

Here you would find this answer:

> I have looked into this issue before, and as it stands at the moment,
>   native android does not support exFAT or NTFS.
>
> Support for additional formatting types are included in some ROMs
>   because they have been specifically coded to do so such as AFAIK which
>   I believe supports NTFS.
>
> I think you are stuck with FAT32 unless you wish to root and flash a
>   ROM that supports alternative formats.

Shortly, it seems it doesn't depend on manufacturer or Android version. It seems to be every Android phone may some issues with NTFS-formatted SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Could [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) be an option? It allows large files and some Android devices support it. Worth a try?